# Which android barcode scanner app is best for scanning 2D codes from phone screen?

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner

Which android barcode scanner apps can scan 2D codes like QR, Data Matrix, aztec etc. from a mobile phone screen (the code is displayed on the phone screen)? I looked at Barcode Scanner and QR Droid and QuickMark but either they don't support many 2D codes or they don't do good scanning from phone screens.

Comment: alas, though ZebraCrossing might be the least bad (as @ChiragRaval said), barcode scanners on smartphones are still a long way from being practical - cute they may be, but they are too slow for any real life application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZXing (pronounced "zebra crossing") is an open-source, multi-format 1D/2D barcode image processing library implemented in Java, with ports to other languages.

[Download ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) from here.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend QR Droid, but as I see, so you do not like. Unfortunately, I do not know another :/
**EDIT:** Try [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ScanLife&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwiY29tLlNjYW5MaWZlIl0.).